# YouTube Player API error 150 on some owned videos

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to use the YouTube IFrame API on a Tizen Web App to show my company video projects, but many of these videos show a "Video unavailable" error, and from the onError event I get an **error code 150**. Of course, all videos are configured to allow embeds.

For example, this video will play fine:

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/XZc76zYrsdU

But this one won't play, and will show the mentioned error:

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/9t4UooKRhBQ

Here's some code that I use to load the YouTube IFrame from within my app:

```
// creating fullscreen div for the YouTube IFrame API to populate
var divYt = document.createElement("div");
divYt.setAttribute("id", "player");
divYt.style.width = "100%";
divYt.style.height = "100%";
divYt.style.position = "absolute";
divYt.style.top = "0";
divYt.style.left = "0";
divYt.style["z-index"] = "9999";
divYt.style["box-sizing"] = "unset";
document.body.appendChild(divYt);

$scope.player = new $window.YT.Player("player", {
    videoId: $scope.videoIdSel,  // the ID of the selected video
    events: {
        "onReady": onPlayerReady,
        "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange,
        "onError": onPlayerError
    }
});
```

If the user selects the first video in the example, everything works fine, but if the second video gets selected, the onPlayerError function gets called instead, returning `data: 150`

Looking up online I've seen some people suggesting the error might be related to a copyright claim, but in this case both of the videos are demonetized, so I don't think that's the problem in my case.

**Note:** this error also happens when pasting the links in a new tab, but not when clicking a link that opens within the same page. I've also noticed that if I open the second embedded video in incognito mode on Chrome, it mysteriously works fine, but of course I can't do that on my web app.

I'm struggling to understand what's causing this problem. Can someone please help me out? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be related to the license policy of the YT player.
The licenses are different in the two URLs you provided.
The first URL(https://www.youtube.com/embed/XZc76zYrsdU) does not have any license whereas the second URL(https://www.youtube.com/embed/9t4UooKRhBQ) does have a license.
The license of the second URL is UMG(Walt Disney Records) and BMI - Broadcast Music Inc.
You can check the license of the second URL @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t4UooKRhBQ&feature=emb_title by clicking 'SHOW MORE'

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I didn't notice this (rather subtle) difference.
Edit: is this intended behavior? Both videos have an otherwise identical copyright situation

Comment: @FabIngenia It seems to be an intended behavior.